# ASP.NET Forms and jQuery Mobile Contradictory Logic

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile

I'm running into what looks like a contradiction between jQuery Mobile and ASP.NET Forms. I have two pages that I'm transitioning between using jQuery Mobile page transitions. The basic structure looks something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="page1" data-role="page">
   <form id="aspNetForm" runat="server">
      Page 1
      <a href="#page2">Page 2</a>
      <!-- Some more ASP.NET controls that require the aspNetForm -->
   </form>
</div>
<div id="page2" data-role="page">
   Page 2
   <a href="#page1">Page 1</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice that the form tag is only present in the first page. That's because ASP.NET only allows one form per page. When I try and move the form tag outside of the page divs jQuery Mobile starts acting strange (specifically the page transitions start looking strange). This becomes a problem when I want to use any sort of ASP.NET web controls that deliver input inside the second page.

Basically these rules exist that essentially lead to a contradiction:

```
ASP.NET:
1) All web controls that deliver an input must be within an ASP.NET form tag
2) Only one ASP.NET form tag can be visible (as in visible=True, not display: block) per page request

jQuery Mobile:
1) All content, including forms, must be within a page div
```

Can anyone think of a way to get around this? I guess I could restrict page2 to only use traditional HTML and not web controls but that doesn't seem like the most elegant solution. Any ideas? Has anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. In my opinion, the simple solution would be to give each page its own .aspx-file. That would work just fine.

If your site is very big, it would also improve performance.

Comment: We've done that in most cases. However there are several cases where this still comes up. For example, popups on mobile phones seem to have the best performance (considering the small screen real estate) when they are injected as separate "pages" (as in <div data-role="page" />) and then a transition effect transitions to the popup and then back again on the close event. Another case is when you have a navigation panel that is always on the page but hidden. Creating it as a second page and transitioning looks really slick. In both cases the transition is part of the usability.